# Apache cannot serve file if its filename contains accented characters

Tags: apache, character-encoding

I am using apache 2.2 server for file sharing,but if my file contains any small latin char sets like é OR ç OR à OR ù or others I cant reach my file.

I think the problem is in the charset configuration.

Comment: Are you talking about special characters in file names or contents?

Comment: right,filenames containing charecters of above kinds

Comment: Nobody cab answer it????

Comment: What operating system is this on? Also, you might try on ServerFault, it's not really a programming question...

Comment: Windows server 2008,I am just looking the confgi line I need to add for this solution on htpdconf file thats all,very easy

Comment: Do you mean that you can't locate it or can't transfer it? If transferring how are you doing it? Transfer them in binary mode. Is this a coding question? More information required.

Comment: I mean I cant locate it,If my URL to locate that file contains any latin character or arabic character or any other than latin1 charachter it fails to locate that file.I am transferring them in binary mode through binary buffers